# Best exponential fit for guitar frets

Tags: fitting

I have an old guitar that has missing the nut (zeroth fret) and also missing the bridge. I want to figure out their position.

So I measured distances between first fret and frets `1` to `18` stored in `a` (`a_1` is obviously `0`). I want to find value of `x` and `y`. Red line on the image is nut of guitar and blue line is bridge of guitar, black lines are frets `1` to `18`.

[image]

Was it an ideal guitar and ideal measurements then there would be a solution for `x` like this:

```
a = Prepend[(-(Table[100/(2^(1/12))^n, {n, 0, 19}] // Differences)) //
      Rest // Accumulate, 0];
Table[(a[[-1]] + x - a[[n]])/(a[[-1]] + x - a[[n + 1]]) == (
   a[[-1]] + x - a[[n + 1]])/(a[[-1]] + x - a[[n + 2]]), {n, 1, 
   Length[a] - 2}] // Solve

(*{{x -> 25 2^(5/12)}}*)
```

Of course the guitar is not made prefect and also my measurements are not perfect so the following will not work:

```
a = {0, 3.3`, 6.33`, 9.28`, 12.04`, 14.63`, 17.08`, 19.39`, 21.6`, 
  23.69`, 25.63`, 27.44`, 29.17`, 30.82`, 32.37`, 33.79`, 35.19`, 
  36.51`}
Table[(a[[-1]] + x - a[[n]])/(a[[-1]] + x - a[[n + 1]]) == (
   a[[-1]] + x - a[[n + 1]])/(a[[-1]] + x - a[[n + 2]]), {n, 1, 
   Length[a] - 2}] // Solve

(*{}*)
```

How to use data stored in `a` to figure out `x` and `y`? I guess `FindFit` could be used here as an approximation for exponential relation between position of frets but I am not sure how.

Comment: The twelfth fret should be exactly in the middle (excepting any intonation adjustments at the saddle). The ratio of fret spacing should be the twelfth root of 2.  So, if x is the twelfth root of 2, then y should be x*a2. Then the saddle is the same distance from the 12th fret as the 12th fret is from the nut.

Comment: You can improve the accuracy by checking a2*x against b3*x^2 and b4*x^3 and so forth, where b3 = a3-a2 (i.e. the actual space between the frets), since a3 spans two frets

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't a Mathematica or even a programming question. It's a basic arithmetic problem.

Comment: @lericr: It is perfect question of finding fit for data.

Comment: I'd go even further and say that you'll get better results from experimentation than from whatever you'll get from an analytical solution.

Comment: I agree:  as written this isn't a *Mathematica* issue.  You might want to check http://www.buildyourguitar.com/resources/tips/fretdist.htm#:~:text=If%20you%20divide%20any%20scale,1.431%22%20(36.48mm)..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note we can rewrite (calling it `aTrue` to distinguish it from the measured `a`)

```
aTrue = Prepend[(-(Table[100/(2^(1/12))^n, {n, 0, 19}] // Differences)) //
      Rest // Accumulate, 0];
```

as:

```
aTrue = -50 2^(11/12) Table[(-1 + 2^(-n/12)), {n, 0, 18}]
```

The distance the bridge in relation to the furthest down fret (`x`) is just the difference between `Limit[-50 2^(11/12)*(-1 + 2^(-n/12)),n->Infinity]` and `aTrue[[-1]]`, or in other words:

```
xTrue = Abs[-50 2^(11/12) + aTrue[[-1]]]
(*25 2^(5/12)*)
```

Let's fit the same type of function as we have for `aTrue` (looks like `k0*Table[(-1 + 2^(-n/12)), {n, 0, Length@a - 1}]`) to your experimental data, and then find the constant `k0` out front to calculate `x`

```
a = {0, 3.3`, 6.33`, 9.28`, 12.04`, 14.63`, 17.08`, 19.39`, 21.6`, 
   23.69`, 25.63`, 27.44`, 29.17`, 30.82`, 32.37`, 33.79`, 35.19`, 
   36.51`};

resid = k0*Table[(-1 + 2^(-n/12)), {n, 0, Length@a - 1}] - a;
kMin = NArgMin[Norm[resid]^2, k0]; (*least squares*)
xFit = Abs[kMin + a[[-1]]]
(*21.8458*)
```

I am not sure about finding the nut position `y`, but wouldn't it just be where the fret board ends on the top? You could also just experimentally move the nut before gluing it down to make sure the notes sound right at each fret.

Comment: Thanks for response, You got almost the same result as mine, look at my own answer.

Comment: I think I will accept your answer as correct, although I think mine is better because of using `FindFit` as was proposed in my question. But you got practically the same result and I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out: It is much more straight forward if we use scale length of guitar `sl` (length between nut and bridge) as fitting parameter, but also `x` from my picture can be used.

```
a = {0, 3.3`, 6.33`, 9.28`, 12.04`, 14.63`, 17.08`, 19.39`, 21.6`, 
   23.69`, 25.63`, 27.44`, 29.17`, 30.82`, 32.37`, 33.79`, 35.19`, 
   36.51`};
FindFit[a, 
 sl/(2^(1/12))^1 - sl/(2^(1/12))^n /. 
  sl -> 2 (x + a[[-1]] - a[[12]]), x, n]
FindFit[a, sl/(2^(1/12))^1 - sl/(2^(1/12))^n, sl, n]

(*{x -> 21.8429}*)
(*{sl -> 61.8258}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's reorganize your data, since we know that the 12th fret is critical.

```
data = a[[12]] - Reverse[Take[Rest@a, 11]]
```

We now have distances from the 12th fret in `data`. Let's also define a critical constant, the 12th root of 2.

```
twelfthroottwo = 2.^(1/12)
```

We expect this relationship for our data:

```
data[[n]] == x*twelfthroottwo^(n - 1) - x
```

where x is the distance from the saddle to the twelfth fret.

Let's try `FindFit` and see what we get.

```
fitResult = FindFit[data, x*twelfthroottwo^y - x, {x}, y]
(* {x -> 26.2586} *)
```

Let's check it:

```
MapIndexed[x*twelfthroottwo^First[#2 - 1] - x - #1 &, data] /. fitResult
(* {0.,-0.248581,-0.534316,-0.871682,-1.22483,-1.56757,-1.93332,-2.31514,-2.73566,-3.20706,-3.61108} *)
```

Doesn't seem great. I suspect that we're giving too much weight to the smaller measurements (which probably have greater relative error).

**Edit**

Ooops, I wrote the wrong relation:

```
fitResult = FindFit[data, x*twelfthroottwo^(y - 1) - x, {x}, y]
(* {x -> 30.9138} *)
```

That matches the least squares approach below.

**End Edit**

Let's try a different way to fit using `LeastSquares`. We'll make an expression that we can feed to `LeastSquares`:

```
relations = MapIndexed[{twelfthroottwo^First[#2 - 1] - 1, #1} &, data]
(* {{0., 0.}, ... , {0.781797, 24.14}} *)

LeastSquares[List /@ relations[[All, 1]], relations[[All, 2]]]
(* {30.9138} *)
```

And let's check:

```
MapIndexed[x*twelfthroottwo^First[#2 - 1] - x - #1 &, data] /. x -> leastsqResult[[1]]
(* {0.,0.0282317,0.0357704,0.00911577,-0.014846,-0.00881912,-0.00507414,0.00457811,-0.00118627,-0.0331753,0.0283497} *)
```

Much better.

Anyway, we have two candidates for where to locate the saddle from the 12th fret.

Caveats: I'm not an expert at statistical analysis. I'm not particularly familiar with `FindFit` nor `LeastSquares`, so there are probably options and usage conventions that are better than what I cobbled together here.